# httpd service stop working when configure the dashboard on the controller node

Tags: openstack-horizon

When I restart the httpd server when configuring the dashboard on the controller node I get the following error:

```
# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

journalctl -xe output:

```
# journalctl -xe

...
Nov 07 16:13:56 node1 polkitd[988]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3279:123978 (system bus name :1.34 [/usr/
Nov 07 16:13:56 node1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
...
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: __import__(name)
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 379, in <modul
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: from local.local_settings import *  # noqa: F403,H303
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py", line 37
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: 'supported_vnic_types': ['*'],
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: ^
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: IndentationError: unexpected indent
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 polkitd[988]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3279:123978 (system bus name :1.34, obj
lines 2264-2290/2290 (END)
```

any idea about it?
Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `journalctl -xe`

Comment: thanks for you reply and the output of journalctl is in the 1 answer. @SimonC

Comment: I have moved the output of `journalctl -xe` to your question. You should delete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the file `/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/local/local_settings.py` at line 37.

Your Python script has an unexpected indent, as told by the journalctl output.

```
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: 'supported_vnic_types': ['*'],
Nov 07 16:13:57 node1 python[3285]: ^ there's an indent here the interpreter doesn't like.
```

I'm not too good with Python, but removing this indent should fix your problem.
In general, it's always a good idea to look at what the system daemon is trying to tell you. 
From experience I can tell you it's a configuration problem 95% of the time.